# What is the best django model field to use to represent a US dollar amount?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I need to store a U.S. `$` dollar amount in a field of a Django model.  What is the best model field type to use?  I need to be able to have the user enter this value (with error checking, only want a number accurate to cents), format it for output to users in different places, and use it to calculate other numbers.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

A [decimal field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) is the right choice for the 
currency value.

It will look something like:

```
credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Unless you want to represent the national debt, in which case max_digits has to be > 20

Comment: decimal_places=2 is not necessarily correct if you need this to support other currencies. Some currencies have three decimal places, and Bitcoin has a whooping 8.

Comment: I think this example is correct almost to all currencies. To represent currencies as Bitcoin, I think is much better to use an integer field to save the amount in satoshis, and then show it to the final user in the representation that you want (BTC, mBTC, etc)

Comment: @LieRyan that's true. We have to take note of modern types of "currency" to prevent any future db modifications. No offence for the use of quotes.

Comment: @BronDavies  SAVAGE

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224462/storing-money-in-a-decimal-column-what-precision-and-scale/ suggests using `max_digits=19, decimal_place=4` to be safe.

Comment: max_digits=6 looks a bit small to me. That means the highest money amount you can store is just 9999.99.

Answer (score 55):

The other answers are 100% right but aren't very practical as you'll still have to manually manage output, formatting etc.

I would suggest using [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money):

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from django.db import models


def SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_currency = MoneyField(
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0,
        default_currency='USD',
        max_digits=11,
    )
```

Works automatically from templates:

```
{{ somemodel.some_currency }}
```

Output:

```
$123.00
```

It has a powerful backend via python-money and it's essentially a drop-in replacement for standard decimal fields.

Comment: *(with error checking, only want a number accurate to cents), format it for output to users in different places, and use it to calculate other numbers.* For such cases, use `DecimalField` is more practical. And I believe it is applied for most people. Using `django-money` as they highlighted, include **Currency** handling. So this is more for project involving transaction such as ecommerce sites, payment gateway, digital currency, banking, etc....

Comment: I'd argue that since they're working with USD -- a currency -- it makes more sense to use a currency-handling library like django-money (python-money) as it makes everything work as you'd expect and affords future feature adjustments. The original question says they need formatting and calculation (as you quoted) and for that you're better off using a currency library instead of a simple decimal field.

Comment: What if I want to add two money fields or do some calculations?

Comment: @saran3h you can work with money instances and perform calculations like any other number (decimal) instance. You can add/subtract, multiply by integers, etc.

Answer (score 45):

```
field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Note that max_digits should be >= decimal_places. This example setting would allow a value up to: 999,999.99

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield

Answer (score 8):

Define a decimal and return a $ sign in front of the value.

```
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def price_display(self):
        return "$%s" % self.price
```

Comment: You do realize that you just created an infinite recursion loop in your property, right?

Comment: Interesting. May I ask how that it?

Answer (score 2):

```
field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Should create a field for PostgreSQL like:

```
 "field" numeric(8, 2) NOT NULL
```

Which is the best way for PostGreSQL stored US dollar amount.

If you need a PostgreSQL field type "double precision", then you need do in django model:

```
field = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: Beware of representing money as a floating point number, as people tend to get unhappy about rounding errors w.r.t. their money.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) for `money` field:

First, install `django-money[exchange]` as shown below:

```
pip install django-money[exchange]
```

*You can install `django-money` without `[exchange]` as shown below but it doesn't have the functions to convert currencies so I recommend to install `django-money[exchange]` as shown above:

```
pip install django-money
```

Next, add `'djmoney.contrib.exchange'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `core/settings.py`:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'djmoney.contrib.exchange',
]
```

Then, run the command below:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then, define a field with `MoneyField()`, `MinMoneyValidator()`, `MaxMoneyValidator()` and [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects) in `MyModel` model in `my_app/models.py' as shown below:

```py
# "my_app/models.py"

from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from decimal import Decimal
from djmoney.models.validators import MaxMoneyValidator, MinMoneyValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    money = MoneyField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, default_currency='USD',
        validators=[
            MinMoneyValidator(Decimal(0.00)), MaxMoneyValidator(Decimal(999.99)),
        ]
    )
```

Then, run the command below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Then, you can add a value on Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

Then, you can get the value with `$` and the value without `$` using `.amount` in `my_app/views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "my_app/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from app.models import MyModel

def test(request):
    print(MyModel.objects.all()[0].money) # Here
    print(MyModel.objects.all()[0].money.amount) # Here
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these below are displayed on console:

```
$12.54
12.54
```

Next, you can convert `12.54 USD` to `... EUR`.

First, go to [Open Exchange Rates](https://%20https://openexchangerates.org/), then sign up to get the exchange rates of currencies:

[image]

Then, copy **App ID** from your dashboard:

[image]

Then, set `OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID` with **App ID** in `core/settings.py`:

```py
# "core/settings.py"
                             # Here
OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID = '368183b0b2644e999ef2a61bd38d0ca3'
```

Then, run the command below:

```
python manage.py update_rates
```

Then, you can convert `12.54 USD` to `... EUR` with `convert_money()` and `Money()` as shown below. *You have to use the value without `$` using `.amount`:

```py
# "my_app/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from app.models import MyModel
from djmoney.contrib.exchange.models import convert_money
from djmoney.money import Money

def test(request):
    money = MyModel.objects.all()[0].money.amount
    print(convert_money(Money(money, 'USD'), 'EUR')) # Here
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, `12.54 USD` is converted to `11.70 EUR` as shown below:

```
€11.70
```

You can see [django-money doc](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which has more details.

And, you can update the exchange rates of currencies every 60 minutes with **celery beat** code in `core/tasks.py` and `core/settings.py` as shown below. ***Open Exchange Rates** can accept 1000 requests per month in Free Plan:

```py
# "core/tasks.py"

from celery import shared_task
from djmoney import settings
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

@shared_task
def update_rates(app_id):
    backend = import_string(settings.EXCHANGE_BACKEND)(
        access_key=app_id
    )
    backend.update_rates()
    print("Successfully updated")
```

*You should put `OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID` and import `app`, `crontab` and `update_rates` just before the celery beat code in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID = '368183b0b2644e999ef2a61bd38d0ca3'

from .celery import app
from celery.schedules import crontab
from .tasks import update_rates

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='*/60'),
        update_rates.s(OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID),
        name='update_rates'
    )
```