# Django Currency Conversion

Tags: python, django, localization, currency

Is there any facility in Django for doing currency conversions? Obviously, rates change day by day but I'm somewhat hopeful that the locale module has some sort of web-service based converter.

There's a snippet here that handles the formatting: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/552/ But I need to localize the values first.

Answer (score 5):

Probably more elegant ways to do this, but it works.

```
currency_in = 'USD'
currency_out = 'NOK'
import urllib2
req = urllib2.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='+currency_in+currency_out+'=X')
result = req.read()
# result = "USDNOK=X",5.9423,"5/3/2010","12:39pm"
```

Then you can split() the result for the modifier.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I hackishly put this in my settings.py, storing the result as USD_TO_EUR (what I needed), and then the code can access this anywhere. With a cron to SIGHUP gunicorn daily (I already had this), this will get updated at least that often.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Install google-currency package

# pip install google-currency

>>> from google_currency import convert  

>>> convert('usd', 'bdt', 1)
```

Output:

```
{"from": "USD", "to": "BDT", "amount": "85.30", "converted": true}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) app for currency conversions in Django-based projects.

It works with different rate sources and provides an interface to perform conversions & money localization:

```
>>> # After app setup & adding rates to the DB
>>> from djmoney.money import Money
>>> from djmoney.contrib.exchange.models import convert_money
>>> value = Money(100, 'EUR')
>>> converted = convert_money(value, 'USD')
>>> converted
<Money: 122.8184375038380800 USD>
>>> str(converted)
US$122.82
```

Formats are easily customizable, you could find the documentation on the project page.

Comment: I tried this but I get an error MissingRate at /customer
Rate EUR -> USD does not exist. I opened a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867845/how-to-solve-missingrate-error-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) to handle money values including the conversion of currencies as shown below. *The example below converts `100 USD` to `... EUR` and if using **celery beat**, you can automatically update the exchange rates of currencies:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from app.models import MyModel
from djmoney.contrib.exchange.models import convert_money
from djmoney.money import Money

def test(request):
    print(convert_money(Money(100, 'USD'), 'EUR')) # Here
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139393/what-is-the-best-django-model-field-to-use-to-represent-a-us-dollar-amount/75372754#75372754) and [django-money doc](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which explain more about how to convert currencies and how to automatically update the exchange rates of currencies with **celery beat**..