# Convert a price field in django to be in a specific currency

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-models, currency

I have a Product model which has a price field and a currency field.
the user can save different products using different currencies. some products are saved in usd, some in gbp, etc'..

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=1, 
        max_digits=4, 
        default=0
    )
    usd = 'USD'
    nis = 'NIS'
    gbp = 'GBP'

    CURRENCY_CHOICES = (
        (usd , 'USD'),
        (nis, 'NIS'),
        (gbp, 'GBP')
    )
    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES,
        default=usd,
        blank=True
    )
```

I want to be able to sort and view all of the products in a single currency.
how can i add a field, `price_in_usd`, which will be set automatically when fields 'price' and 'currency' will be set?

something like this for example:

```
price_in_usd = convert_price_to_usd()
convert_price_to_usd():
 if currency == GPB:
    return price*1.25
 if currency == NIS:
    return price*0.33
```

Comment: Instead of implementing this yourself, it might be better to use a library like [**`django-money`**](https://github.com/django-money/django-money). It has support for converting between currencies.

Comment: What do you mean "my problem is with django not having a setter/getter" ???

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `clean()` method to handle this kind of behaviors.

```
class Product(models.Model):

    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0)
    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES,
        default=usd,
        blank=True
    )
    price_in_usd = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0, editable=False)

    def clean(self):
        if self.price and self.currency:
            self.price_in_usd = convert_price_to_usd(self.price, self.currency)
```

See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) to know exactly when the `clean()` method will be invoked. According to what you do, you may have to call explicitely `full_clean()` yourself before calling `save()`. Also `clean()` won't be called if you use `QuerySet.update()` or `bulk_create()` for instance.

Another way to handle this might be to implement it at SQL level using triggers for instance.

---

However, if you want the price in USD to be updated (hourly, daily or whatever) to always match the current change rate, you will have to use a cron job to update `price_in_usd` on a regular basis.

If you don't need to sort the data by `price_in_usd` on the database level, another solution is to use a property:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0)
    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES,
        default=usd,
        blank=True
    )

    @property
    def price_in_usd(self):
        return convert_price_to_usd(self.price, self.currency)
```

Comment: thanks, i used the clean() method and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You better use [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) which can handle money values including the conversion of currencies as shown below. *The code below converts `USD` to `EUR`:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from app.models import Product
from djmoney.contrib.exchange.models import convert_money
from djmoney.money import Money

def test(request):
    money = Product.objects.all()[0].price.amount
    print(convert_money(Money(money, 'USD'), 'EUR')) # Here
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139393/what-is-the-best-django-model-field-to-use-to-represent-a-us-dollar-amount/75372754#75372754) and [django-money doc](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which explain more about how to convert currencies.