# Store large decimal number in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In Android,
I going to store 8 digits in Sqlite but when i retrieved values from edittext to Float/Double then value was displaying with specific number format ie. "E" or some time add "." in values.

Edit text value is  : 99989888
Result is : 9.998989

How i can resolve this issue?
I can't use BigDecimal because it's not supported by Sqlite and > operator.

Comment: What do you mean with "displaying"? Isn't the edit box is the *only* place where it's displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `long` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use TEXT representation of BigDecimal and convert it in/out when you need it. Another aproach is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39626427/4655462)