# How to get the BigDemical in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bigdecimal

I'm grabbing the data of the database. If integer I can use `getInt`, If String I can use `getString`. But `BigDecimal` I don't know what to use...

Please Help. Thanks in advance!

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
    String txnno = cursor.getString(1);
    String name = cursor.getString(2);
    String txndate = cursor.getString(3);
    BigDecimal amount = cursor.getDouble(4);
    String description1 = cursor.getString(5);
    String createddate = cursor.getString(7);

    mList.add(new Model(id, txnno, name, txndate, amount, description1, createddate));
}
```

Comment: how are you adding it to table ?

Comment: I created a row.xml for this. I just want to get Bigdecimal then It done. I would like to know if `Int = getInt` , `String = getString`, then bigDecimal is = to what? @Qasim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)`:

```
BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best optimal choice would be :  To get the value using getString() method and then converting it to BigDecimal using suitable constructor.

Refer To: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal

Related links:
For more :[How can I store a BigDecimal (Java) value in a Real (SQlite) column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023706/how-can-i-store-a-bigdecimal-java-value-in-a-real-sqlite-column)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the advantage of using big decimal of say double is that you get precision. if you are converting from a double to a big decimal, as suggested by the first answer, you are likely to have those same precision problems double has. It is always better to convert a string to a big decimal.