# Float format when json serializing in elixir

Tags: json, elixir, elixir-poison

Elixir uses scientific notation by default for floats greater then 1000. This causes an undesired side effect during json serialization.

```
iex(5)> val = 1000.00
1.0e3
iex(11)> Poison.encode(val)
{:ok, "1.0e3"}
```

The output I would like is

```
iex(11)> Poison.encode(val)
{:ok, "1000.00"}
```

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960798/get-rid-of-scientific-notation#44961056) that uses `:erlang.float_to_binary(0.005 * 2.7 / 100, [:compact, {:decimals, 10}])` or `:io.format("~f~n",[0.005 * 2.7 / 100])`, but this would require to patch `Poison` or to manually check all data before encoding.

Is there a cleaner way to force the default flot to binary format in elixir ?

Comment: How is Poison (or any other serializer) supposed to know how many trailing zeroes you expect to be left?

Comment: It's not about trailing zeros, it's about scientific notation `1000.0` instead of  `1.0e3`. And the question is how to define the format that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Poison` allows to implement [`Poison.Encoder`](https://github.com/devinus/poison#encoder) protocol. The implementation for `Float` obviously [exists](https://github.com/devinus/poison/blob/master/lib/poison/encoder.ex#L221), that’s why I’d suggest to wrap your floats into custom `FloatStruct` upfront:

```rb
defmodule FloatStruct do
  defstruct value: 0.0, format: [:compact, {:decimals, 10}]
end

defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: FloatStruct do
  def encode(%{value: value, format: format}, options) do
    Poison.Encoder.BitString.encode(
      :erlang.float_to_binary(value, format), options)
  end
end
```

I understand that this would require traversing nested terms to wrap `Float`s with `FloatStruct`s, but I don’t see any easier approach. I might be wrong, though.

---

One might support both mentioned in the OP formats for free:

```rb
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: FloatStruct do
  def encode(%{value: value, format: format}, options) do
    Poison.Encoder.BitString.encode(
      format(value, format), options)
  end

  defp format(value, format) when is_list(format),
    do: :erlang.float_to_binary(value, format)
  defp format(value, format) when is_binary(format),
    do: :io.format(format, [value])
end
```