# Money data type issue

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

Just wondering about SQL Server Money data type:

```
------- SCRIPT 1
declare 
  @test table (
    Seg varchar(1),
    amt money
)

insert @test
select 'a', -427614103835526.00 union all
select 'a', -219289921481827.00 union all
select 'a', -169175063383313.00 union all
select 'a', -151094936902350.00 union all
select 'a', 522155575758567.00  union all
select 'a', 395662864132351.00  union all
select 'a', 187076841800608.00 

select SUM(amt) from @test

------ SCRIPT 2

 
declare
 @amt money

set @amt = 137721256088510.00
```

As you see, the script 1 will failed

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type money."

I tried to move the content to Excel and got the amount of the 2nd Script and it runs well. Is there any kind of explanation on this behavioral?

Comment: The final value isn't the only value that matters. As you aggregate you go over/under the min/max value and the error occurs. In truth, `money` is best avoided anyway. Switch to `decimal` with an appropriate scale and precision

Comment: For example, let's say you have a `tinyint` and the values `254`, `2` and `-100`. The `SUM` of those values is `156` which fits in a `tinyint`. If, however, the data engine `SUM`s the values `254` and `2` first then an error occurs, as `256` is too large to fit in the data type.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overflows and to maintain a predictable ~15 significant digits in calculations, convert to float and then back.

```
select cast(SUM(cast(amt as float)) as money) from @test
```

This is not just for MONEY.  Floating point math is more predictable and useful than the [rules for decimal precision and scale in calculations with DECIMAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which sacrifice precision to allow for potentially large results.

EG

```
declare @a decimal(38,8) = 2.0001
select @a*@a d, cast(@a as float)*cast(@a as float) f
```

outputs

```
d                                       f
--------------------------------------- ----------------------
4.000400                                4.00040001

(1 row affected)
```

Because the product of two decimal(38,8) values is decimal(38,6).

```
 select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@a*@a,'Precision') Precision, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@a*@a,'Scale') Scale
```

outputs

```
Precision             Scale
--------------------- -----------
38                    6
```

Comment: IMO - Casting to `decimal(19,4)` would be preferable. `SUM()` of that is `decimal(38,4)` and it avoids any imprecision from round tripping through `float`. Generally people value precision when dealing with financial calculations and the multiplication is not relevant

Comment: agree with DECIMAL(19, 4) since it is commonly used. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224462/storing-money-in-a-decimal-column-what-precision-and-scale) can give you more inshght

Comment: In this case, decimal(19,4) is fine.  In the case of more complex financial calculations loss of precision in a small intermediate result could be magnified in the final result.