# Extension method must be defined in non-generic static class

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, extension-methods

Error at:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
```

Probable cause:

```
public static IChromosome To<T>(this string text)
{
    return (IChromosome)Convert.ChangeType(text, typeof(T));
}
```

Attempted (without static keyword):

```
public IChromosome To<T>(this string text)
{
    return (IChromosome)Convert.ChangeType(text, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Just when I thought _that_ was actually a [good error message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/07/07/659259.aspx).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you remove "this" from your parameters it should work.

```
public static IChromosome To<T>(this string text)
```

should be:

```
public static IChromosome To<T>(string text)
```

Comment: This worked, but can you explain WHY!?  I am tired of getting correct answers to solve problems but not understanding the problem or the solution after I do.

Answer (score 19):

The class containing the extension must be static. Yours are in:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
```

which is not a static class.

You need to create a class like so:

```
static class ExtensionHelpers
{
    public static IChromosome To<T>(this string text) 
    { 
        return (IChromosome)Convert.ChangeType(text, typeof(T)); 
    } 
}
```

To contain the extension methods.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was caused because I created a static method inside the partial class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window{

......

public static string TrimStart(this string target, string trimString)
{
    string result = target;

    while (result.StartsWith(trimString)){
    result = result.Substring(trimString.Length);
    }

    return result;
    }
}
```

When I removed the method, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Because your containing class is not static, Extension method should be inside a static class. That class should be non nested as well. [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)