# email address validation, how to?

Tags: regex, validation, exchange-server, email-validation

I'm validating email addresses in a c# app, beside the regular expression I'm planning to add some advanced validation by communicating with the mail exchanger and get a response whether such email address exists or not

does any one has a good idea of doing that ? i know a website that can check it :

```
http://www.ip-address.org/verify/email-checker.php
```

but I'm not sure what is the approach the website uses for validation.
i tried emulating a telnet session on my mail exchanger and then sending commands

```
MAIL FROM and RCPT TO
```

but it doesn't work, either the connection is blocked, or the response is erroneous

Comment: Whatever other answers you get, **please** don't write your own.

Comment: @Hbcdev : you mean, real names, IPs...of course not, but thanks for the reminder

Comment: Did you search SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address might be useful.

Comment: thanks, but it seems like a real issue...everywhere :), think i'm going to stick with my regex for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you describe no longer works and variations on it don't work either-- the mail server will respond incorrectly or mark you as a spammer, ref. http://www.spamresource.com/2010/11/smtp-address-validation-bad-idea.html

Mail-Bee NET has some features like this and the documentation says it can work, but you need to convince the other mail servers that you are also a mail server. http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/getting_started_with_address_validator.html

Either way, it sounds like a risky project and likely to get your mail server blacklisted.