# Get email address from the url with and without escape character of @ in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Url as shown below

http://www.mytestsite.com/TesPage.aspx?pageid=32&LangType=1033&emailAddress=myname%40gmail.com

I would like to have the email address from the url

**Note**

The email address may have the escape character of @ sometimes.

ie it may be *myname%40gmail.com* or *myname@gmail.com*

Is there any way to get the email address from a url, such that if the that have the matching regx for an email patten and retrieve the value.

Here is the code that i have tried

```
string theRealURL = "http://www.mytestsite.com/TesPage.aspx?pageid=32&LangType=1033&emailAddress=myname%40gmail.com";

string emailPattern = @"^([\w\.\-]+)(((%40))|(@))([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$";
  Match match = Regex.Match(theRealURL, emailPattern);
  if (match.Success)
     string campaignEmail = match.Value;
```

If anyone helps what went wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If possible, don't use a regular expression when there are domain-specific tools available.

Unless there is a reason not to reference `System.Web`, use

```
var uri = new Uri(
    "http://www.mytestsite.com/TesPage.aspx?pageid=32&LangType=1033&emailAddress=myname%40gmail.com");
var email = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("emailAddress");
```

Edit: If (for some reason) you don't know the name of the parameter containing the address, use appropriate tools to get *all* the query values and *then* see what looks like an email address.

```
var emails = query
    .AllKeys
    .Select(k => query[k])
    .Where(v => Regex.IsMatch(v, emailPattern));
```

If you want to improve your email regex too, [there are plenty of answers about that already](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=regex+email).

Comment: The query string parameter can vary..
How can it possible without using the query string parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Rawling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27959761/1185053) in response to the comment

> The query string parameter can vary.. How can it possible without using the query string parameter name.

The follwing code will produce a list (`emails`) of the emails in the supplied input:

```
var input = "http://www.mytestsite.com/TesPage.aspx?pageid=32&LangType=1033&emailAddress=myname%40gmail.com";
var queryString = new Uri(input).Query;

var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

var attribute = new EmailAddressAttribute();

var emails = new List<string>();
foreach (var key in parsed.Cast<string>())
{
    var value = parsed.Get(key);
    if (attribute.IsValid(value))
        emails.Add(value);
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", emails)); // prints: myname@gmail.com
```

<sub>See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554735/1185053) for email parsing technique.</sub>