# Identical property in WPF TextBox to "type" for "input" in HTML

Tags: c#, html, wpf

If I understood correctly, a `TextBox` in WPF is similar to the `input` in HTML. Therefore, is there a property for the `TextBox` that plays the same role as `type` for `input`?
I would like to have something with a similar behaviour than with `<input type="email"/>`.

Thanks

Comment: Which behaviour of `type="email"` do you want in your application? You might want to rephrase your question to ask specifically about that behaviour.

Comment: I would like users without a physical keyboard to have a virtual keyboard adapted to email addresses (without the space bar but with "@", ".", etc.) and to deactivate auto-correct for this field.
So, someone who types one's email address from his cellphone will have an appropriate keyboard and will not encounter an issue with the auto-correct because what he is typing does not appear in the cellphone's dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in equivalent to `type` for the WPF `TextBox`. You will have to implement that kind of logic yourself.

Try starting with this other question: [Email address input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882173/email-address-input-validation)

WPF was designed for desktop use, and desktops were designed primarily for physical keyboards. I don't know of any way to customize/interact with the Windows on-screen keyboard.