# Regex match hangs my program

Tags: c#, regex

We have an application where we are using the following `RegEx` to validate email.

```
private string _regularExpression = @"^(("".+?"")|([0-9a-zA-Z](((\.(?!\.))|([-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w]))*[0-9a-zA-Z])*))@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$";
Regex _reg = new Regex(_regularExpression);
```

However we have a incorrect email in source:

> abcd1090ihavenoidea.what.going.wrong.here

for which the program hangs. We are still unable finding out which part we are doing wrong here?

Comment: take this one `^([A-Z|a-z|0-9](\.|_){0,1})+[A-Z|a-z|0-9]\@([A-Z|a-z|0-9])+((\.){0,1}[A-Z|a-z|0-9]){2}\.[a-z]{2,3}$`

Comment: @PatrickHofman It actually does on my computer

Comment: How would it? It doesn't even use the email address mentioned.

Comment: One update, I just tried out it in [here](https://regex101.com/) , it says *Catastrophic backtracking*...any common way to fix it?

Comment: @Nitro.de thanks mate, but we got rid of it using timeout, just wanted to know what went wrong here.

Comment: Please do not use regex to parse or validate email addresses. Whereas it's possible, the regex is incredibly complicated to get right for all valid addresses. Instead, use something like what's described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program hangs because with this regex you get a *Catastrophic backtracking*. It stopped on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/jJ0iU2/1) after *121 628* steps. I try to lower the input string to see how catastrophic it was: it took *88 063* steps to understand that `abcd1090ihav.w` is not a valid email.

Since you're using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), you may read :

- [C# code to validate email address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1365407/2307070)
- [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Although I don't think regex is the right tool for validating emails, if OP prefers to use it, I found the following long pattern from [HERE](http://emailregex.com/), which claims the best match. And the site is dedicated for regex solutions:

```
^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])$
```

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jT9rA1/6).

Also take a look at this site: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: [Boom, broken](https://regex101.com/r/jT9rA1/4). I don't think regex is a good thing for email.

Comment: @Thomas: Agree with you.