# how to check if email is in valid format or not in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xcode, email-validation

My code is this can anyone correct this or any other solution to this problem.
 This is what I've got so far but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
  int i=0,f=0;
    string n = Console.ReadLine();
    for (i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)          
        if(n[i]=='@' || n[i] == '.')              
            f = f + 1;               
    if(f==2){
console.writeline('correct')
}
    else{
console.writeline('Incorrect')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# code to validate email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public bool IsValidEmail(string email)
 {
    return new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(email);
 }
```

Comment: Regular expressions are no good means for validating email addresses according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/3959259).

Answer (score 0):

...or this

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
try {
    var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
    return addr.Address == email;
}
catch {
    return false;
}
}
```