# Can you have "optional multiple ANY characters"?

Tags: regex

I currently have the regex string `@"[0-9a-zA-Z].+@.+[0-9a-zA-Z]$"`
The problem with it is that it requires 2+ characters before and after the "@", so an input like a@a won't be valid, while it should

What I need is a way to do `.+?` without the "Any character" (?) turning into a lazy quantifier

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `+` to `*` after each `.`

```
[0-9a-zA-Z].*@.*[0-9a-zA-Z]$
```

https://regex101.com/r/sNMQsw/3

Comment: The problem is that it HAS to start with a-z0-9A-Z, can't start with a "{", and your answer would allow for that

Comment: Could you provide a test suit of valid/invalid cases?

Comment: Answer updated with new regex

Comment: Perfect, didn't know about the * char, thanks!

Comment: If it's an email validation for commercial use consider using existing solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address