# I want email id validation like following should accept normal email id as well as following email ids

Tags: c#, .net

**fara+alther@gmail.com
ashika@123.43.34.110
 
ananya@[321.43.20.40]
 
"saraali"@gmail.com**
I am using below `regex` pattern to identity :

`*([-a-zA-Z0-9_\\:;,(). @"[\]<>]+)@((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})*` but it does not allow me
to accept numbers,dots,square brackets after '@'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# code to validate email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address)

Comment: No i tried it  bt its not working