# System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden() not working when common language runtime exceptions is check

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

I use visual studio 2017
And in **Exception settings**  *common language runtime* exceptions is **checked**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden()]
public static void testFunc()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch {}
}
```

the Debuger stop on  `testFunc();` and show exeption

there is why to ignore specific function in the **code**?

Not in GUI settings  (the debugger does not break to other programmers)

In other words how to uncheck that in the code

[image]

Comment: The docs say _"The common language runtime attaches no semantics to this attribute. It is provided for use by source code debuggers. For example, the Visual Studio debugger does not stop in a method marked with this attribute and does not allow a breakpoint to be set in the method."_ - why do you think exceptions thrown in this method would be handled differently?

Comment: [exemple code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374644/10899908)

Comment: I don't really see the relevance of that link. If you've checked "break on all exceptions" in the Exception Settings, then all the exceptions are "checked", and as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown) say _"If you select an exception in the Exception Settings window, debugger execution will break wherever the exception is thrown, **no matter whether it's handled**. Now the exception is called a first chance exception"_