# Why are tests not evaluating properly even if the function is working properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, testing, mstest

I have added MSTests to my C# WinForms project. To test if they are working right, I wanted to test the following function:

```cs
public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    return new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(email);
}
```

To do this I have written these two tests:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Test_IsValidEmail_True()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(IsValidEmail("test@test.pl"),"Good mail test");
}
[TestMethod]
public void Test_IsValidEmail_False()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(IsValidEmail("test@test"), "Bad mail test");
}
```

The function works correctly and checks if the email is correct.

That means that the funtcion `IsValidEmail("test@test")` returns `false`.  However the second test passes only if I input it with for example "test", but if I input `test@test` it will not pass and outputs:

> Message: Assert.IsFalse failed. Bad mail test

Why is this test failing?

Here is how I tested the function if it works manually:

```cs
MessageBox.Show("test@test.pl - " + IsValidEmail("test@test.pl"));
MessageBox.Show("test@test - " + IsValidEmail("test@test"));
```

[image: test 1]
[image: test 2]

Comment: Clearly `IsValidEmail("test@test")` is returning true, so the actual question should be "Why does `EmailAddressAttribute.IsValid("test@test")` return true?"

Comment: @MatthewWatson but I wrote in my question that the function works correctly and if I input "test@test" in a running application, it shows it as incorrect, so, my question is correct.

Comment: When I try `Console.WriteLine(new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid("test@test"));` it prints `true`, so I cannot reproduce your result.

Comment: I tested `"test@test"` in .Net Core 3.1 and it's `True`.
Also why do you unit test other's library?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have added proof in my question

Comment: Please add your framework version as well. Is your unit test run on the same framework version?

Comment: @LouisGo My application is .NET Framework 4.6.1 and MSTests are .NET Core 2.1

Comment: And you just answered your own question. You can't expect different frameworks have the same outcome.

Comment: @LouisGo what does that mean? I can't use MSTests for WinForms?

Comment: [`ParseAddress`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs,87b2cacf203ba13e) in .NET Framework has quite different implementation than in [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Mail/Common/System/Net/Mail/MailAddressParser.cs,ec5a62b2e40e5590)

Comment: @TK-421 `EmailAddressAttribute` is also looks very different, compare [.NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs,54) regex and simple check in [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs,c3ae85dfd8a9f58c) You may have a look at existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address) for some examples of your own regex

Comment: Yes so this is the difference in behaviour between .Net 4.6.1 and later versions (including .Net core).

Comment: Here we go: https://www.zpqrtbnk.net/posts/net-framework-4-7-2-emailaddressattribute-validation/

Comment: @MatthewWatson so I have too old version of .net in my project (4.6.1) and that is why it returns that "test@test" is false?

Comment: @TK-421 It's not really that it's "too old", it's just that the behaviour has changed between that version of .Net and the version you're running the unit tests with.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you very much.