# Order by multiple columns with different types in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a newbie with Oracle. In SQLite, PostgreSQL or MSSQL I can do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id, email
```

Here is the definition of USERS:

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS" (
 "ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
 "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255)
)
```

Id is NUMBER type and email is VARCHAR type.

When I run the above SELECT query in Oracle it will raise the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Is there anyway to do that in Oracle?

Thank for your interest.

Comment: Please post a description of users or its CREATE statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `email` field is a `CLOB` and not a `VARCHAR`.  You cannot `ORDER BY` a `CLOB`.

If your column is a `CLOB` then you can `CAST()` the field to order by:

```
select *
from users
order by id, cast(email as varchar2(50))  -- or whatever length you want.
```

## See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89b33/2)

Comment: Thank you a lot bluefeet! Your suggestion helps me. I changed your query a bit and it worked: SELECT * FROM users ORDER CAST(id as varchar(20)), email

Comment: Are you sure ID is a NUMBER and not a CLOB as the error is indicating? Your question and the above comment don't make sense.

Comment: Yes, ID is a NUMBER, that's why I have to cast ID to varchar to order with email.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the real type of `email` column. It just seems to be CLOB which is not applicable for order by.

Obviously, there is not need to store emails that are longer than 4000 chars.

So CLOB should be replaced with VARCHAR2(255).

See [What is the maximum length of a valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address).

There may be some problem with Oracle type mapping in your ORM.

Comment: How do you know it's not the actual email message?

Comment: Good point - probably not ;)  (This is a good example of good naming conventions. If the column was called `email_address` everything would be clear)

Comment: Maybe `email` is the entire contents of the user's mailbox? :P

Answer (score 0):

try it with column positions also-
(this means you should not use * - which i would recommend anyway...)

```
select id, email from users order by 1,2
```

it should also be possible to order by the first portion of the CLOB by applying some string concatenation function in th eorder by clause.

Comment: Thank you Randy, but ordering by the column position also raise the error ORA-00932.