# What is the maximum length of a display name in an email address

Tags: validation, email

According to the question "[What is the maximum length of a valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address)", the maximum length of the address is 254. But I like to know what would be the maximum length of the display name:

```
Display Name <my@examplemailaddress.net>
```

Following this link https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ietf-822/current/msg00086.html the size is unlimited but practically according this link https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ietf-822/current/msg00088.html the size would be 72 characters. But I believe this answer is a bit outdated? What would be reasonable limit for today?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you ask the *maximal* length allowed by the specs (the normative source is [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) as of *current_timestamp*) then, indeed, there is no limit, since folding allows you to have an [unlimted length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3) of any field (while still respecting the [advised](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1.1) 78 [or the larger 998] character limit).

Practical limit is a very subjective question, since "practical" would be the length which is fully displayed by "most" clients and environments; now that's pretty hard to calculate.

I would say the **upper limit** of practicality would be the total length of 78 characters from the "From:" header up to the last ">" character of the email address, since longer ones may probably break up while displaying in almost all environments, which would give you **around 40 characters** to use even for longer email addresses.

Most clients, however, probably expects to display around 20-25 characters under normal circumstances.

These are all *displayed* characters and not the actual length in bytes of a whatever way encoded address (especially for long utf-8 codes).

Comment: If a line should not be longer than 998 characters and the maximum length of an email address is 254, might the recommended maximum length for the display name be like 998 - 254 - 2 ("<>") - 6 ("From: ") = 736 ?

Comment: @Trendfischer I guess recommendation should consider the displayability of the display name: it if's too long it won't be displayed, ever: I guess most client is simply unable to display strings longer than the allocated space for DN. What you wrote is based on a rather technical limit, but I see no practical reason for it: it's too long for humans (at least 9 "usual lines" long) and unnecessarily limited for machines. What is your purpose anyway? :-)

Comment: When I asked the question four years ago, I had to set a maximum size for a database field for the display name. Then I had to set additional display names for system generated sender adresses based on locations with street names and additional infos. To generate these display names, I had to guess a practical limit. So both values are relevant, imho.