# How to get all the two characters long substrings separated by dot (.) from an email address in SQL server. I want Scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one email column that is having values like this `'claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us'`. I want to take two characters strings between dot (to check for the countries and states codes).

i want result like this

```
col1=re,mn,us
```

Comment: Why only those three values? Why not `dit`?

Comment: What database do you use ?, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ... ?

Comment: I want to comapare with country code and state code. Thats why i want only two characters between the dot(.).

Comment: Am working on SQL server.

Comment: Did you try using the [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) or [STRING_SPLIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

To do exactly what you've asked; i.e. pull back just the 2 char codes from within the email address's domain, you could use a function such as this:

```
create function dbo.fn_Get2AlphaCharCodesFromEmail
(
    @email nvarchar(254) --max length of an email is 254: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address
) returns nvarchar(254)
as
begin
    declare @result nvarchar(254) = null
    , @maxLen int = 254 
    ;with cte(i, remainder,result) as 
    (
        select cast(0 as int)
        , cast('.' + substring(@email,charindex('@',@email)+1,@maxLen) + '.' as nvarchar(254))
        , cast(null as nvarchar(254))
        union all
        select cast(i+1 as int)
        , cast(substring(remainder,patindex('%.[A-Z][A-Z].%',remainder)+3,@maxLen)as nvarchar(254))
        , cast(coalesce(result + ',','') + substring(remainder,patindex('%.[A-Z][A-Z].%',remainder)+1,2) as nvarchar(254))
        from cte
        where patindex('%.[A-Z][A-Z].%',remainder) > 0
    )
    select top 1 @result = result from cte order by i desc;
    Return @result;
end
go

--demo
select dbo.fn_Get2AlphaCharCodesFromEmail ('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us') 
--returns: re,mn,us
select dbo.fn_Get2AlphaCharCodesFromEmail ('claudio.passerini@uni.123.dit.mnx.usx')
--returns: NULL
```

**Explanation**

- Create a function called `fn_Get2AlphaCharCodesFromEmail` in the schema `dbo` which takes a single parameter, `@email` which is a string of up to 254 characters, and returns a string of up to 254 characters.

  ```
  create function dbo.fn_Get2AlphaCharCodesFromEmail
  (
      @email nvarchar(254)
  ) returns nvarchar(254)
  as
  begin
      --... code that does the work goes here
  end
  ```
- declare the variables we'll be using later on.

  - `@result` holds the value we'll be returning from the function
  - `@maxLen` records the maximum length of an email; this makes it slightly easier should this length ever need to change; though not entirely simple since we have to specify the 254 length in our column & variable definitions later on anyway.

    declare @result nvarchar(254) = null
    , @maxLen int = 254
- Now comes the interesting bit.  We create a common table expression with 3 columns:

  - `i` is used to record which iteration each record was produced in; the highest value of `i` is the last record to be created.
  - `remainder` is used to hold the yet-to-be processed characters from the email.
  - `result` is used to record the 2 char codes; each new row adds another value to this column's comma separated values.

    ;with cte(i, remainder,result) as 
    (
        --code to iterate through the email string, breaking it down, goes here
    )
- this gives us our first row in the cte "table".

  - The cast statements throughout this part are to ensure we have a consistent data type, as data types in a CTE are implicit, and not always correct
  - we initialise `i` (i.e. the first column) with value `0` to say that this is our first row (we could choose pretty much any value here; it doesn't matter
  - we initialise `remainder` (i.e. 2nd column) as the part of the email address which follows the `@` character; i.e. the email's domain.
  - we initialise `result` (i.e. 3rd column) as `null`; as we've not yet found a result (i.e. a 2 char string within the email's domain)
  - there is no `from` component as we're just getting data from the `@email` variable; no tables/views/etc are required.

    ```
    select cast(0 as int)
    , cast('.' + substring(@email,charindex('@',@email)+1,@maxLen) + '.' as nvarchar(254))
    , cast(null as nvarchar(254))
    ```
- `union all` is used to combing the first result(s) with the results of the next (recurring) statement.  NB: The CTE code before this statement is run once to give initial values; the code after is run once for each new set of rows generated.

  ```
      union all
  ```
- The recurring code in the CTE is applied to new rows in the CTE until no new rows are generated.

  - `i` takes the value of the previous iteration's row's `i` incremented by 1.

    ```
    select cast(i+1 as int)
    ```
  - `remainder` takes the previous iteration's remainder, and removes everything before (and including) the next 2 character code (result).
  - `patindex('%.[A-Z][A-Z].%',remainder)` returns a number giving the location of the a string containing a dot followed by 2 letters followed by a dot, occurring anywhere in the input string

    ```
    , cast(substring(remainder,patindex('%.[A-Z][A-Z].%',remainder)+3,@maxLen)as nvarchar(254))
    ```
  - `result` uses the same logic as `remainder`, only it takes the 2 characters found, rather than everything after them.  These characters are added on to the end of the previous iteartion's row's result value, separated by a comma.

    ```
    , cast(coalesce(result + ',','') + substring(remainder,patindex('%.[A-Z][A-Z].%',remainder)+1,2) as nvarchar(254))
    ```
  - the `from cte` part just says that we're referencing the same "table" we're creating; i.e. this is how the recursion occurs

    ```
    from cte
    ```
- the where statement is used to prevent infinite recursion; i.e. once there are no more 2 char codes left in the remainder, stop looking.

  ```
      where patindex('%.[A-Z][A-Z].%',remainder) > 0
  ```
- Once we've found all the 2 char codes in the string, we know that the last row's result will contain the complete set; as such we assign this single row's value to the `@result` variable.

  ```
  select top 1 @result = result
  ```
- the from statement shows we're referencing the data we created in our `with cte` statement

  ```
  from cte
  ```
- the `order by` is used to determine which record comes first (i.e. which record is the `top 1` record).  We want it to be the last row generated by the CTE.  Since we've been incrementing `i` by 1 each time, this last record will have the highest value of `i`, so by sorting by `i desc` (descending) that last generated row will be the row we get.

  ```
  order by i desc;
  ```
- Finally, we return the result generated above.

  ```
  Return @result;
  ```

---

**Alternative Approach**

However, if you're trying to extract information from your emails, I'd recommend an alternate approach... have a list of values that you're looking for, and compare your email with that, without having to break apart the email address (beyond splitting on the @ to ensure you're only checking the email's domain).

```
declare @countryCodes table (code nchar(2), name nvarchar(64)) --you'd use a real table for this; I'm just using a table variable so this demo's throwaway code
insert into @countryCodes (code, name) 
values 
     ('es','Spain')
    ,('fr','France')
    ,('uk','United Kingdom') 
    ,('us','USA') 
    --etc.

--check a single mail
declare @mail nvarchar(256) = 'claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us'
if exists (select top 1 1 from @countryCodes where  '.' + substring(@mail,charindex('@',@mail)+1,256) + '.' like '%.' + code + '.%')
begin
    select name from @countryCodes where  '.' + substring(@mail,charindex('@',@mail)+1,256) + '.' like '%.' + code + '.%'
end
else
begin
    select 'no results found'
end
--check a bunch of mails
declare @emailsToCheck table (email nvarchar(256))
insert into @emailsToCheck (email)
values
('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us')
,('someone@someplace.co.uk')
,('cant.see.me@never.never.land')
,('some.fr.address.hidden@france.not.in.this.bit')

select e.email, c.name
from @emailsToCheck e
left outer join @countryCodes c
on '.' + substring(email,charindex('@',email)+1,256) + '.' like '%.' + code + '.%'
order by e.email, c.name
```

Comment: Am not asking like this.

Comment: I want scalar function..I have one email column that is having values like this 'claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us'. I want to take two characters strings between dot (to check for the countries and states codes).

i want result like this

col1=re,mn,us

Comment: that function should work like this..select functionname('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us')..reslut col1=re,mn,us

Comment: No worries, I've created a function which gives you what you're after... however I recommend you consider the alternative approach as that would be more flexible/useful in most of the use cases I can think of...

Comment: Whatever I tried your function is working as VERY GOOD.Thank you for given your time.

Comment: In future it will help me.THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU..:)

Comment: Hi brother.Now am using your code superb think.HATS OFF

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function to split strings.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    set @delimiter = coalesce(@delimiter, dbo.cSeparador());

    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Using this function you can get all your country&state codes :

```
select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us', '.')
where len(splitdata) = 2
```

You can modify that query to concatenate the result on a single string :

```
 SELECT
 STUFF((SELECT ',' + splitdata
        FROM dbo.fnSplitString('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us', '.')
        WHERE len(splitdata) = 2
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Here is how you put it into an scalar function :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCountryCodes](@email nvarchar(max)) returns nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT
            STUFF((SELECT ',' + splitdata
                   FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@email, '.')
                   WHERE len(splitdata) = 2
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''));
END
```

You call it like this :

```
select dbo.fnCountryCodes('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us')
```

Alternatively you can create a table-valued function that returns all the 2 characters long substrings from the domain of a mail address :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCountryCodes] (@email NVARCHAR(MAX))   
RETURNS @output TABLE(subdomain1 nvarchar(2), subdomain2 nvarchar(2), subdomain3 nvarchar(2), subdomain4 nvarchar(2), subdomain5 nvarchar(2)) 
as
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @subdomain1 nvarchar(2);
  DECLARE @subdomain2 nvarchar(2);
  DECLARE @subdomain3 nvarchar(2);
  DECLARE @subdomain4 nvarchar(2);
  DECLARE @subdomain5 nvarchar(2);

  DECLARE CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS CURSOR FOR select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString(@email, '.') where len(splitdata) = 2;
  OPEN CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS;
  FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS INTO @subdomain1;
  FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS INTO @subdomain2;
  FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS INTO @subdomain3;
  FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS INTO @subdomain4;
  FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS INTO @subdomain5;
  CLOSE CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS;
  DEALLOCATE CURSOR_SUBDOMAINS;

  INSERT INTO @output (subdomain1, subdomain2, subdomain3, subdomain4, subdomain5) 
              values (@subdomain1, @subdomain2, @subdomain3, @subdomain4, @subdomain5)
  RETURN 
END
```

You use it like that :

```
select * from dbo.fnCountryCodes('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us')
```

Comment: After from keyword why you're using function name instead of table name?

Comment: This is a Table-Valued function, it returns a dataset (the list of substrings from your string) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Sorry Brother I want scalar function only.

Comment: That's very easy, now that you have split it you just have to use a cursor to loop through that dataset so you can return it as you prefer.

Comment: Please give me any scalar function.

Comment: @Krish  You want to avoid cursors as much as possible.  They almost always perform worse than a proper set based approach.

Comment: Ok, here you have it. It still is a table-valued function, because an scalar function only returns single values, but now it returns all the strings in a single row.

Comment: I have updated the solution to return the result on a single string, as demanded on your updated question. Now you have both possibilities: an scalar function and a table-valued function.

Answer (score 0):

If yo want individual columns you will need to pivot your data after splitting out your strings with a table valued function as per Marc's answer.  If you are happy having them in rows, you can just use the `select` statement inside the brackets.

## Query to get the data

```
declare @t table (Email nvarchar(50));
insert into @t values('claudio.passerini@uni.re.dit.mn.us'),('claudio.passerini@uni.ry.dit.mn.urg'),('claudio.passerini@uni.rn.dit.mn.uk');

select Email
        ,[1]
        ,[2]
        ,[3]
        ,[4]
        ,[5]
        ,[6]
from(
    select t.Email
            ,s.Item
            ,row_number() over (partition by t.Email order by s.Item) as rn
    from @t t
        cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.Email,'.') s
    where len(s.Item) = 2
) a
pivot
(
    max(Item) for rn in([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) pvt
```

## Table valued function to split out the strings, courtesy of Jeff Moden

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
```

Comment: your'e function is working good.but i want only single row it's splitting 6 rows

Comment: @Krish  My script already returns one row per Email, with up to six instances of a 2 character string in separate columns.  Do you mean you want the results in one column?  If so, you should update your question to reflect this.