# Minimal max_length of a Django CharField to store the output of the sign method of a Signer object (django.core.signing)

Tags: python, django, sign, maxlength

I have to sign a value, in my case emails, and I have to store the signed value in a Django CharField.
I am using the Signer.sign method of the django.core.signing module.
Since I would like to insert also the max_length parameter for the db field, my question is, what would be the minimal value I can put in the max_length in order to always successfully store it in the db.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the signing token length grows with the input value:

```py
>>> from django.core.signing import Signer
>>> signer = Signer()
>>> signer.sign('a')
'a:JRYbTbX2xBKZAgJxbzUzsl80vIQ'

>>> signer.sign('ab')
'ab:ThbCyQ9bQpAX4vMAmYSEtbtF7Y4'

>>> signer.sign('abc')
'abc:4_rTdYDe18bPklTTKYIsJaB9_oM'

>>> signer.sign('abcd')
'abcd:RzGFLsNgRv-LQ4lEorvNPjGH5LM'

>>> signer.sign('abcde')
'abcde:oOdfJjZ14Jz2F4aHD3pQMBC9fAA'

>>> signer.sign('abcdefghijkl')
'abcdefghijkl:Wz1gPy4QS7ZoCyXuKgUFG-ofxpU'
```

However, according to my testing, the maximum size of the token is `27`. According to this answer [What is the maximum length of a valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address) maximum length of an email address is `254` characters. `max_length` attribute of your `TextField` should be `282` (`254`+`27`+`1` for separator).

Comment: The signature uses HMAC with SHA-1 as its hash function, and then encodes the output in base64, stripping away any padding character `=` from the base64 output. The output of SHA-1 is 20 bytes, and base64 increases the length by 33%, so the maximum of 27 bytes that you found in your tests is correct.

Answer (score 0):

this is what they have given on the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signing/).

```
from django.core.signing import Signer
>>> signer = Signer()
>>> value = signer.sign('My string')
>>> value
'My string:GdMGD6HNQ_qdgxYP8yBZAdAIV1w'
```

the sign string is of length of 28 (including ':') plus the length of your email string.to be on the safe side I would suggest you to use Django [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) instead of CharField

Comment: There is no limit on `max_length`. The only limit is that a MySQL index has a maximum length of 767 bytes, which means that if you're using an index or unique constraint on a `CharField` with a character set that uses 3 bytes per character, _then_ the limit is 255. When using a different database or no index, there is no limit on the maximum length (but there may be other limits, e.g. on the size of a row).