# What type and size should encrypted email have in mysql InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, encryption, innodb

I have an email attribute in my database. I stored it in the `TINYTEXT`. But now I decided to encrypt it using `AES_ENCRYPT` and store it encrypted. With what type and size for the email should I go to avoid any problems whatsoever?

From [the](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) documentation I decided to store email as `VARBINARY(60)`. Here are my thoughts on it:

```
16 × (trunc(string_length / 16) + 1)
I want my email to be VARCHAR(32)
16 × (trunc(32 / 16) + 1) = 48
But in order to avoid padding problems I will use 60 instead of 48.
So, the type of the encrypted email will be VARBINARY(60)
```

Am I right?

Comment: I usually just store as VARCHAR with length 80 (I've seen some pretty long email addresses haha)

Comment: Email addresses [can be up to 254 characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of a VARCHAR, as the name suggests, is based on the number of characters in the data. The length of a VARBINARY column is based on the number of bytes (octets) in the value. You cannot calculate the the appropriate size for the column without reference to the character set being used for the data.

Trying to store VARBINARY data in a column that isn't long enough will result in an error rather than truncated data so you need to allow for the longest possible value and for the fact that your character set might allow for multi-byte characters. The simplest way to get this is to query the information_schema.columns table and get the current size from `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` (rather than `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`) and then apply your formula to that

e.g.

```
SELECT 16 * (FLOOR(CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH / 16) + 1)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yrdb'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'yrtable'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'email'
```

You don't then need to a add a bit extra to take care of padding because that's already taken account of within your formula.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Answer**:  `VARBINARY(48)`, as you computed.  But, to handle longer email addresses, `BLOB`.

**Messier Answer**:

`AES_ENCRYPT` expands the string some, so 254 will exceed 255 after encrypting.  Also, it returns non-character bytes.

`BLOB` is a simple answer.  `VARBINARY(256)` would probably also work, but might not have any advantage.  (I suspect utf8 characters could make it exceed 256.)

Do you need to index it?  That could lead to other issues.

If you limit emails to 32 ascii characters, what percentage of the world will you exclude or truncate?