# Registration with restricted email domain, PHP validation

Tags: php, validation

I have this line of code that I want to apply to a login page. I want to restrict the login for only user with certain domain name like "@mycompany.com" no other user can register without having this domain.

But the problem is that I can't get it to work, it passes all domains I have tried and does not return to false

The codes are copied and paste from two different forumpages, one that has no rules for domains and the second code with rules for restricted domains ( from line "//validate tld")that I pasted in and edited. Where does it go wrong, at the moment I can't see where?

```
     public static function validateUserEmail($user_email, $user_email_repeat)
    {
    if (empty($user_email)) {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_FIELD_EMPTY'));
        return false;
    }

    if ($user_email !== $user_email_repeat) 
   {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_REPEAT_WRONG'));
        return false;
    }

    // validate the email with PHP's internal filter
    // side-fact: Max length seems to be 254 chars
    // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address
    if (!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        //validate tld
        $validTlds = str_replace(".", "\.", VALID_EMAIL_TLDS);
        $validTlds = "\.".str_replace(",", "|\.", $validTlds);

        //$validTlds = str_replace(",", "|\.", $validTlds);
        $emailArr = explode("@", $user_email);

        $emailTld = $emailArr[1];

        if ($emailTld !== 'mycompany.com')
        {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_DOES_NOT_FIT_DOMAIN'));
        return false;

        }
        if (!preg_match('/^[-a-z0-9]+('.$validTlds.')\z/', strtolower($emailTld))) {

            //check main domain here
            $exValidTlds = explode(",", VALID_EMAIL_TLDS);
            $exValidTlds = array_map('trim', $exValidTlds);
            foreach($exValidTlds as $tld) {//if exist then

        if(!strstr($emailTld, ".".$tld)) {
        if($tld !== strrchr($emailTld, $tld)) {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_DOES_NOT_FIT_PATTERN'));
        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_DOES_NOT_FIT_PATTERN'));
        return false;
        }
    }
        return true;
    }
```

This is the original code I started with and the validation of domain I added in later. All this validation domain code seems to be ignored...

```
    public static function validateUserEmail($user_email, $user_email_repeat)
{
    if (empty($user_email)) {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_FIELD_EMPTY'));
        return false;
    }

    if ($user_email !== $user_email_repeat) {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_REPEAT_WRONG'));
        return false;
    }

    // validate the email with PHP's internal filter
    // side-fact: Max length seems to be 254 chars
    // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address
    if (!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_DOES_NOT_FIT_PATTERN'));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**EDIT...**

I finally made it to work and this is how, so far it is working for me... The goal is that I don't want other people outside the organisation to be able to log in to the website.

```
        if (filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $server = strstr($user_email, '@');
        if ($server !== '@mycompany.com') {
        Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_DOES_NOT_FIT_PATTERN'));
        return false;    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your not operator is on the wrong side of the variable.  It should be like this...

```
if ($emailTld !== 'mycompany.com')
```

Comment: Yup. Because `!$emailTld` is evaluating to `false`, which will never `== 'mycompany.com'`.

Comment: did change the operator but it still except all domains I'm hitting it with.... there is some errors somewhere.... thanks