# Why is this Knex migration not forcing a column to be unique?

Tags: sqlite, knex.js

I'm creating a SQLite database with this Knex migration. When I review the DB in SQLiteStudio, it doesn't indicate that the email column is unique. Is there a mistake I'm missing?

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .createTable('users', users => {
            users.increments();
            users.string('email', 128).unique().notNullable();
            users.string('password', 256).notNullable();
        })
```

Generated DDL code:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id       INTEGER       NOT NULL
                           PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email    VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR (256) NOT NULL
);
```

Alternatives I've tried that didn't work:

-Switching order of unique() and notNullable()

`users.string('email', 128).notNullable().unique()`

-Creating a separate line to add the Unique constraint

```
        .createTable('users', users => {
            users.increments();
            users.string('email', 128).notNullable();
            users.string('password', 256).notNullable();
            users.unique('email');
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unique, you're just not going to see it in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. SQLite sets a `UNIQUE` constraint by [creating an index](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) with the `UNIQUE` qualifier. Take the following Knex migration, for example:

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.debug().createTable("users", t => {
    t.increments("id");
    t.string("name").unique();
  });
```

Note `debug()`, very handy if you want to see what SQL is being generated. Here's the debug output:

```
[
  {
    sql: 'create table `users` (`id` integer not null ' +
      'primary key autoincrement, `name` ' +
      'varchar(255))',
    bindings: []
  },
  {
    sql: 'create unique index `users_name_unique` on `users` (`name`)',
    bindings: []
  }
]
```

As you can see, a second statement is issued to create the `UNIQUE` constraint. If we now go and look at the database, we'll see something like:

```
07:48 $ sqlite3 dev.sqlite3
sqlite> .dump users
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement,
  `name` varchar(255));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `users_name_unique` on `users` (`name`);
COMMIT;
```

As an aside, you may wish to do more research about the possible length of user emails. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574698/122643) as a starting point.