# Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

**Migration error on Laravel 5.4 with `php artisan make:auth`**

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter tabl    e `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> [PDOException]                                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Answer (score 580, accepted):

According to the [official Laravel 7.x documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-indexes), you can solve this quite easily.

Update your `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to contain:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

> Alternatively, you may enable the `innodb_large_prefix` option for your database. Refer to your database's documentation for instructions on how to properly enable this option.

Comment: Be careful about this solution. If you index email fields for example, stored emails can only have a max length of 191 chars. This is less than the official RFC states.

Comment: This solution suggest by Laravel
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17508
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-failing-on-php-artisan-migrate-after-php-artisan-makeauth

Comment: It is working and is a valid solution, but I just wanted to point out, that there are possible pitfalls using this approach.

Comment: I hope this solution doesn't come to bite me in the arse in the future, but for now, this works.  I'll have to be careful with how I index emails though.

Comment: why exactly 191 characters @absiddiqueLive

Comment: Solution is working . Same solution also here : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: You have to uncomment
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
in bootstrap/app.php

Comment: Works for me on Laravel 5.7 and shared hosting without SSH. Thanks!

Comment: This is an ugly hack which hobbles your code to accommodate a bad/outdated DB configuration, and it's being presented as if it was an actual solution.

Comment: this is second time that you save my time

Comment: not working for voyager 1.7 with laravel v10, php 8, my sql 8

Answer (score 281):

I'm just adding this answer here as it's the ***`quickest`*** solution for me. Just set the default database engine to **`'InnoDB'`** on

***`/config/database.php`***

```
'mysql' => [
    ...,
    ...,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
 ]
```

then run ***`php artisan config:cache`*** to clear and refresh the configuration cache

EDIT:
Answers found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)** may explain behind the scenes of this one

Comment: perfect solution. Better with some documentations for future explanation

Comment: A quick update: I wrote "InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC" insted of just "InnoDB", as mentioned in other comments below, and it worked. However I don't know what it means and how it affect the Laravel application. If anyone know, I would really appreciate the heads up.

Comment: perfect thanks. Also work with Laravel 9

Answer (score 250):

I don't know why the above solution and the official solution which is adding

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

in `AppServiceProvider` didn't work for me.
What worked for was editing the `database.php` file in `config` folder.
Just edit

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

and it should work, ***although you will be unable to store extended multibyte characters like emoji***.

**This is an ugly hack and don't do if you want to store string in non english language, emoji**

I did it with Laravel 5.7.

**Don't forget to stop and launch again the server.**

Comment: Using this character set will only allow you to save Standard ASCII, and not multibyte special characters like those from Arabic, Hebrew, most European scripts, and of course emoji. see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15128103/4233593

Comment: I think you missed this part `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` at the top.

Comment: @KoushikDas what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Now I am on 6.0. I think I did it initially with 5.7 or 5.6 maybe.

Comment: The `utf8mb4` collation is there for a reason, I recommend to use it if you can.

Comment: These are defaults, right? They can be overridden by column, right?

Comment: This is an ugly hack, but you're explaining why it's bad, in your answer.

Comment: this comment helped me too. the `AppServiceProvider` didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 66):

**Laravel 7.X | 8X | 9X:** Simple **Solution**.

**Option-1:**

```
php artisan db:wipe
```

Update these values(Below) of **mysql array** in **/config/database.php**

> **`'charset' => 'utf8',`**
> **`'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',`**

And then

```
php artisan migrate
```

**It's Done!**  Migration Tables will be created **successfully**.

---

**Option-2:**

**Use** `php artisan db:wipe` **or** delete/drop all the tables of your database manually.

**Update** your **AppServiceProvider.php** **[** Located in **app/Providers**/AppServiceProvider.php **]**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); 
}
```

And then

```
php artisan migrate
```

**It's Done!**

**Pitfall:** I would like to mention of @shock_gone_wild 's comment

> Be careful about this solution (Option-2). If you index email fields for example,
> stored emails can only have a max length of 191 chars. This is less
> than the official RFC states.

---

**Optionally** I Tried out these possible ways (like below) **but doesn't work**.

`php artisan config:cache`  `php artisan migrate:fresh`

`php artisan migrate:reset`

Comment: it's works like butter , im using Laravel 10. thanks!

Comment: @GigaTera, Glad to know that helps.

Answer (score 32):

This issue is caused in Laravel 5.4 by the database version.

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes) (in the `Index Lengths & MySQL / MariaDB` section):

> Laravel uses the `utf8mb4` character set by default, which includes
>   support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are running a
>   version of MySQL older than the 5.7.7 release or MariaDB older than
>   the 10.2.2 release, you may need to manually configure the default
>   string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create
>   indexes for them. You may configure this by calling the 
>   `Schema::defaultStringLength` method within your `AppServiceProvider`.

In other words, in `<ROOT>/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
// Import Schema
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
// ...

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function boot()
{
    // Add the following line
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}

// ...

}
```

But as the comment on the other answer says:

> Be careful about this solution. If you index email fields for example,
>   stored emails can only have a max length of 191 chars. This is less
>   than the official RFC states.

So the documentation also proposes another solution:

> Alternatively, you may enable the `innodb_large_prefix` option for your
>   database. Refer to your database's documentation for instructions on
>   how to properly enable this option.

Answer (score 21):

For someone who don't want to change `AppServiceProvider.php`.
(In my opinion, it's bad idea to change `AppServiceProvider.php` just for migration)

You can add back the data length to the migration file under *`database/migrations/`* as below:

**`create_users_table.php`**

```
$table->string('name',64);
$table->string('email',128)->unique();
```

**`create_password_resets_table.php`**

```
$table->string('email',128)->index();
```

Comment: This can be a problem since emails can be up to 255(ish) characters

Comment: You are right @HalfCrazed, but I suggest this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297272

Answer (score 21):

works like charm for me!

Add this to config/database.php

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

instead of

```
'engine' => 'null',
```

Comment: Setting `'engine' => 'InnoDB'` only didn' t work for me but adding `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` like this worked.

Answer (score 20):

I have solved this issue and edited my *`config->database.php`* file to like my database **`('charset'=>'utf8')`** and the **`('collation'=>'utf8_general_ci')`**, so my problem is solved the code as follow:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: Do note that not all Unicode characters are supported by utf8.

Answer (score 15):

I am adding two [sollution](https://youtu.be/dsUlfKXdljU) that work for me.

**[1st sollution is](https://youtu.be/dsUlfKXdljU):**

1. Open **database.php** file insde **config** dir/folder.
2. Edit `'engine' => null,` to `'engine' => 'InnoDB',`

   This worked for me.

**2nd sollution is:**

1. Open **database.php** file insde **config** dir/folder.
   2.**Edit**
    `'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
   'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',`

   to

   `'charset' => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',`

**Goodluck**

Answer (score 15):

**1-** Go to ***`/config/database.php`*** and find these lines

```
'mysql' => [
    ...,
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    ...,
    'engine' => null,
 ]
```

and change them to:

```
'mysql' => [
    ...,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    ...,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
 ]
```

**2-** Run ***`php artisan config:cache`*** to reconfigure laravel

**3-** Delete the existing tables in your database and then run ***`php artisan migrate`*** again

Comment: but according to documentation "utf8" will use the deprecated utf8 mode though?

Comment: I just changed engine part from null to InnoDB and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 12):

Open this file here: /app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

And Update this code as my image:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome Anthony Phillips

Answer (score 10):

I have found two solutions for this error

**OPTION 1:**

Open your **user** and **password_reset** table in *database/migrations* folder

And just change the length of the email:

```
$table->string('email',191)->unique();
```

---

**OPTION 2:**

Open your ***`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`*** file and inside the ***`boot()`*** method set a default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The solution no one tells is that in **Mysql v5.5** and later **InnoDB** is the default storage engine which does not have this problem but in many cases like mine there are some old mysql ini configuration files which are using old **MYISAM** storage engine like below.

```
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
```

which is creating all these problems and the solution is to change default-storage-engine to **InnoDB** in the Mysql's *ini* configuration file once and for all instead of doing temporary hacks.

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

And if you are on **MySql v5.5** or later then **InnoDB** is the default engine so you do not need to set it explicitly like above, just remove the `default-storage-engine=MYISAM` if it exist from your `ini` file and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use this suggestion in conjunction with the string length, charset, and collation changes in order to get this to work with laravel 6 and mysql 5.6. Hopefully this helps others in the future.

Comment: @CasperWilkes you don't have to do any of that string length, charset stuff. Check your Mysql system variable like this `show global variables like 'innodb_large_prefix';` it should be **ON**. If it's **OFF** then you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851332/5348400) answer on how turn it on. And [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) is more information about innodb_large_prefix on dev.mysql.com.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't want to make any change in laravel configurations so your solution solved the problem with laravel 9.9

Answer (score 9):

**In laravel 9**

First set the default database engine to `InnoDB` on

`/config/database.php`

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```

then run `php artisan config:cache` to clear and refresh the configuration cache.

`php artisan db:wipe`

Change these values of mysql array in /config/database.php as follows
`'charset' => 'utf8',  'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',`
Then

`php artisan migrate`
That's all! Migration Tables will be created successfully.

Comment: Worked beautifully

Comment: No need to change the collation of the database. The problem is related to the fact that many MySQL installations use MyISAM (or equivalent) as the default engine, be it because of old versions, upgrade from old versions or simply because people like MyISAM. Just changing the storage engine from MyISAM to InnoDB solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of setting a limit on length I would propose the following, which has worked for me.

Inside:

> config/database.php

replace this line for mysql:

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

with:

```
'engine' => null,
```

Answer (score 6):

**in database.php**

-add this line:

'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As already specified we add to the AppServiceProvider.php in App/Providers

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;  // add this

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); // also this line
}
```

you can see more details in the link bellow (search for "Index Lengths & MySQL / MariaDB")
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations

**BUT WELL THAT's not what I published all about!** the thing is even when doing the above **you will likely to get another error** (that's when you run `php artisan migrate` command and because of the problem of the length, the operation will likely stuck in the middle. **solution is below**, and the user table is likely created without the rest or not totally correctly)
**we need to roll back**. the default roll back will not work. because the operation of migration didn't like finish. you need to delete the new created tables in the database manually.

**we can do it using tinker as in below:**

```
L:\todos> php artisan tinker

Psy Shell v0.8.15 (PHP 7.1.10 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> Schema::drop('users')

=> null
```

I myself had a problem with users table.

after that you're good to go

`php artisan migrate:rollback`

`php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 4):

As outlined in the Migrations [guide](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes) to fix this, all you have to do is edit your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file and inside the boot method set a default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

*Note: first you have to delete (if you have) **users** table, **password_resets** table from the database and delete users and password_resets entries from **migrations** table.*

To run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the `migrate` Artisan command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

After that everything should work as normal.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change in AppServiceProvider then you need to define the length of email field in migration. just replace the first line of code to the second line.

create_users_table

```
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('email', 50)->unique();
```

create_password_resets_table

```
$table->string('email')->index();
$table->string('email', 50)->index();
```

After successfully changes you can run the migration.
Note: first you have to delete (if you have) **users table**, **password_resets table** from the database and delete users and password_resets entries from migration table.

Answer (score 3):

`Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` will define the length of all strings 191 by default which may ruin your database. You must not go this way.

Just define the length of any specific column in the database migration class. For example, I'm defining the "name", "username" and "email" in the `CreateUsersTable` class as below:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 191);
            $table->string('username', 30)->unique();
            $table->string('email', 191)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just modified following line in *`users`* and *`password_resets`* migration file.

Old : `$table->string('email')->unique();`

New : `$table->string('email', 128)->unique();`

Answer (score 3):

The recommended solution is to enable `innodb_large_prefix` option of MySQL so you won't be getting into subsequent problems. And here is how to do that:

Open the `my.ini` MySQL configuration file and add the below lines under the `[mysqld]` line like this.

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_large_prefix = 1
innodb_file_per_table = ON
```

After that, save your changes and restart your MySQL service.

Rollback if you need to and then re-run your migration.

---

Just in case your problem still persists, go to your database configuration file and set

`'engine' => null,` to `'engine' => 'innodb row_format=dynamic'`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

In order to **avoid changing anything in your code**, simply **update your MySQL server to at least 5.7.7**

Reference this for more info : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: Nope, the Mariadb 10.1.41 in 18.04 also has this error.

Answer (score 2):

This is common since Laravel 5.4 changed the default database charater set to utf8mb4. What you have to do, is: edit your App\Providers.php by putting this code before the class declaration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Also, add this to the 'boot' function
`Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any data assigned already to you database do the following:

1. Go to app/Providers/AppServiceProvide.php and add

> use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

and inside of the method boot();

> Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

2. Now delete the records in your database, user table for ex.
3. run the following

> php artisan config:cache
>
> php artisan migrate

Comment: It worked but need to add  `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` `use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;` is already there. Hope you correct it

Answer (score 2):

Try with default string length **125** (for MySQL 8.0).

`defaultStringLength(125)`

Answer (score 1):

I think to force StringLenght to 191 is a really bad idea.
So I investigate to understand what is going on.

I noticed that this message error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Started to show up after I updated my MySQL version. So I've checked the tables with PHPMyAdmin and I've noticed that all the new tables created were with the collation **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** instead of **utf8_unicode_ci** for the old ones.

In my doctrine config file, I noticed that charset was set to utf8mb4, but all my previous tables were created in utf8, so I guess this is some update magic that it start to work on utf8mb4.

Now the easy fix is to change the line charset in your ORM config file.
Then to drop the tables using utf8mb4_unicode_ci if you are in dev mode or fixe the charset if you can't drop them.

For Symfony 4

> change **charset: utf8mb4** to **charset: utf8** in *config/packages/doctrine.yaml*

Now my doctrine  migrations are working again just fine.

Answer (score 1):

first delete all tables of the database in the localhost

Change Laravel default database (utf8mb4) properties in file config/database.php to:

'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',

after then
Changing my local database properties utf8_unicode_ci.
php artisan migrate 
it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might run into this, my issue was that I was making a column of type `string` and trying to make it `->unsigned()` when I meant for it to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The approached that work here was pass a second param with the key name (a short one):

```
$table->string('my_field_name')->unique(null,'key_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error even though I already had (actually *because* I already had)
Schema::defaultStringLength(191); in my AppServiceProvider.php file.

The reason is because I was trying to set a string value in one of my migrations to a value higher than 191:

```
Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->primary(['order_id', 'product_id', 'attributes']);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->string('attributes', 1000); // This line right here
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Removing the 1000 or setting it to 191 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my local database server type from **"mariadb"** to **"mysql"** fixed this for me without having to edit any Laravel files.

I followed this tutorial to change my db server type: https://odan.github.io/2017/08/13/xampp-replacing-mariadb-with-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set a string length of the indexed field as follows:

```
  $table->string('email', 200)->unique();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Lumen:

Add to `.env` file

```
DB_ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few lines in the /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf or wherever your config is:

```
innodb-file-format=barracuda
innodb-file-per-table=ON
innodb-large-prefix=ON
innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC'
```

and `sudo service mysql restart`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465235/778234

See the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html

Answer (score 0):

Need to create database using following command.

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and then run following command to migrate database tables.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error running "php artisan migrate". You can alter the table you want to update by writing this :

```
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;');
```

In your migration script. Example :

```
class MyMigration extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 */
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;');        
    Schema::table('table_name', function ($table) {
        //....
    });
}

/**
 * Undo the migrations.
 */
public function down()
{
    //....
}
}
```

And then run `php artisan migrate` again

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to go to your database and change:

```
default_storage_engine to InnoDB
```

You most likely have there MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem with Laravel 8

1. open config\database.php and change

   'charset' => 'utf8mb4',

   'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',

   to

   'charset' => 'utf8',

   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
2. run php artisan config:cache
3. php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

kinds regards

Comment: Please include an explanation of how your solution solves the problem, it helps people learn why the problem occured in the first place!