# Laravel Migration Error : Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter tabl e users add unique users_email_unique(email))
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071
>   Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

whats wrong? im using laravel 5.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)

Answer (score 7):

Refering to [Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error) and [Laravel's migration guide](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes):

> As outlined in the Migrations guide to fix this all you have to do is edit your AppServiceProvider.php file and inside the boot method set a default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: not work... this work in laravel 5.4
i try in laravel 5.3 i get the same error

Comment: This worked for me when using the default `config\database.php` settings `'engine' => null`

Answer (score 2):

```
open create_user_tabel and then write one line inside up function.
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
e.g

    public function up()
    {      
      Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
    }
```

It will work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from the database basically..If you try to increase the length of that column by phpmyadmin, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> As outlined in the Migrations guide to fix this all you have to do is
>   edit your AppServiceProvider.php file and inside the boot method set a
>   default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot(){
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

After that everything should work as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In case, the above solutions or the official solution which is adding

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

doesn't work. Try to edit the database.php file in config folder. Just edit

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

and it should work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to contain:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot() {
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the other suggestions work. This worked for me:

In `config/database.php` replace:

```php
'engine' => null',
```

with:

```php
'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-was-too-long