# voyager php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, voyager

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length
>   is 1000 bytes (   SQL: alter table `translations` add unique
>   `translations_table_name_column_name_foreign_key_locale_unique`(`table_
>   name`, `column_name`, `foreign_key`, `locale`))
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

`AppServiceProvider.php` this way did not worked I can not fix this error any way to fix it?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot() 
{
    Schema::`defaultStringLength`(191); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me when I tried to install voyager. After few digging I found these two answers which working.

**Solution 01**

```
* /config/database.php *

'mysql' => [
    ...,
    ...,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
 ]
```

**Solution 02**
 editing the database.php file in config folder.(Same file in above answer) Just edit,

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

I found these from [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa) issue answers. So all credit should go to @dexterb and @Koushik Das

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

to

```
use Schema;
```