# Migration error during creation of table in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

I'm using xampp as server in my laravel project. While creating migrations, I'm facing an error: only one migration table can be created; others are not being created.

This is the error:

```
**Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length
is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664

    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just
the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|
  Exception trace:
  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your database.php file in the config folder as show below

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

and it should work. If it doesn't work then update AppServiceProvider.php in app/Providers/ as shown below.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //Import Schema

function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //Solved by increasing StringLength
}
```

Comment: thank you brother i appreciate your help hope to stay in contact

Comment: @CYIMANAFaisal Which solution did you use? can you accept (click the check mark below up and down arrows) the answer and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //Import Schema

function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); 
}
```

Hope that helps.