# Laravel Migration - keyname too long despite just being "test"; MySQL Error 42000

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

The migration looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateExtensiontablesRegistry extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('extensiontables_registry', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('extensiontable_name')->nullable(false);//->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique('extensiontable_name', 'test');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('extensiontables_registry');
    }
}
```

Now, when I run it, I get the following errors to my cmd:

```
In Connection.php line 669:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t
  oo long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `extensiontables_reg
  istry` add unique `test`(`extensiontable_name`))


In Connection.php line 463:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t
  oo long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Why is that? I mean, "test" cant be a too long keyname, can it? I also tried this approach:
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

But it didnt help either :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)

Comment: @MCMXCII unfortunately no :/

Comment: which version of laravel are you running ? what's the version of your mysql driver ? are you using mariaDB ?

Comment: @N69S Im using Laravel Framework Lumen (6.2.0) (Laravel Components ^6.0) according to artisan.
Im using MariaDB, yes, latest portable distribution of XAMPP: https://xampp.site/download/xampp-portable/

MariaDB should be this accorind to startup:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 15
Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: had the same issue with mariaDB 10.1 and this fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245921/4369919

Comment: @N69S well, as I already said to MCMXCII, this answer so far didnt help me :/
In my E:\aether-backend\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php  I added the boot() function as described, but nothing changed. Do I need to refresh anything via console or the like before these changes are applied?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might not be a "proper" solution, but it worked for me:
Just download a version of XAMPP with a more recent distribution of mariaDB, at least one above 10.1 (e.g. 10.2 and so on).
Here is a link to a portable XAMPP version with mariaDB 10.4:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.4.2/