# Why I got Specified key was too long with laravel migration?

Tags: mysql, laravel

In laravel 8 / mysql 5.7 defining table with index :

```
Schema::create('community', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('question_title', 1000);
    $table->string('question_slug', 1005)->unique();

    $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('question_point')->default(0);

    ...
    $table->index(['status', 'question_title'], 'community_status_question_title_index');
});
```

I got error :

```
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes (SQL: alter table `community` add index `community_status_question_title_index`(`status`, `question_title`))
```

I wonder why limit in 3072 was broken, as question_title has 1000 chars length and status is bool
and how it can be fixed ?

**MODIFIED** :
I get decision from poinetd branch, but adding in file : /app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

I tried to modify value :

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(2000);
```

But got the same error anyway...

Thanks!

Comment: what is your charset ?

Comment: default latin_swedish_ci. Actually only english is used

Comment: @mstdmstd, Have you checked here before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED

Comment: edit database.php under config folder use utf8 (watch out for multiplebyte chars) 'charset'=>'utf8','collation'=>'utf8_unicode_ci',