# Artisan migrate error:PDOException::"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes"

Tags: mysql, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

In config folder database 'charset' => 'utf8mb4' and 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' are like that when i am trying to php artisan migrate i get this error message
1   C:\wamp64\www\laravel-project-laracast\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:492
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes")

2   C:\wamp64\www\laravel-project-laracast\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:492
PDOStatement::execute()

After reading on this 2 links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa) (perfectionist1 answer) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql) I figured it out how to work it for the moment
The problem is that I have changed :
'charset' => 'utf8mb4' into 'charset' => 'utf8'
The problem is that utf8mb4 supports emoji and BMP while the utf8(utf8mb3) it does not support emoji and BMP
How do I make my database support utf8mb4 cause right now I get that error message when I use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)

Comment: Is the same link as my link1

Comment: Also if I try to add 191 default length  /app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php, stored emails can only have a max length of 191 chars. This is less than the official RFC states and I don't want to have any limitations. Since 2017 Laravel has change and maybe there is a batter answer @RonvanderHeijden