# Laravel Migration sql error 1071 for session ID defined as (`id`);

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to migrate My laravel project from inmotion to hostgator, when I try to upload the sql file I get this error

> --
> -- Indices de la tabla `sessions`
> -- ALTER TABLE `sessions`   ADD UNIQUE KEY `sessions_id_unique` (`id`) MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

the instance thats throwing the error is this

```
--
-- Indices de la tabla `sessions`
--
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `sessions_id_unique` (`id`);
```

I am using a shared hosting with sql 5.6 - the same one is being used at the previous hosting. I also tried MariaDB but the same problem.

Also I added

```
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

to the boot method at AppServiceProvider.php but it still wont work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)

Comment: What is your database collation? check it from `config/database.php` => `mysql` => `collation`

Comment: I used this first
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
didnt work - then tried this
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',

still doesnt work