# Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: laravel, migrate

[enter image description here][1]After creating a new project, I migrate and it gives this error

This project is completely raw and no changes have been made
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAYop.png)

After creating a new project, I migrate and it gives this error

This project is completely raw and no changes have been made

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)

Comment: Please read: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix is your /app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php must contain

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

If not work then try change database charset also

Comment: Thanks, problem solved
I just had a question: Why should a raw Laravel project have to make this change to work?
And what exactly is this change for?

Comment: This not only related to Laravel.  Alternatively, you may enable the innodb_large_prefix option for your database or maybe charset of your database.  But in this case my answer was quick fix or checking probably reason for this error

Comment: I suggest updating your database to a later version or at least read the documentation

Comment: thanks
Can I have your Telegram ID to contact you?

Comment: Thanks @fingram_uz my telegram address