# Troubleshooting Laravel's database connection error

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am a novice with Laravel and I'm attempting to establish a connection to my MySQL database. I've created a fresh Laravel installation and when I configure the database values in my `.env` and `database.php` files, I consistently encounter an error on the website that displays the following message.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'practicelaraveldb.sessions' doesn't exist

Then it prompts me to run the migrate command `php artisan migrate`, and I do, but then I get the error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (Connection: mysql,
> SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> ```
>   at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:813
>     809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>     810▕                 );
>     811▕             }
>     812▕ 
>   ➜ 813▕             throw new QueryException(
>     814▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>     815▕             );
>     816▕         }
>     817▕     }
> ```

I followed the above error's comments and changed the email field in the user's table, and I am still getting errors. Is it really this complicated trying to get a simple database connection? I'm sure I must be missing something here. I followed the directions in the documentation and some YouTube videos.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x#databases-and-migrations

Comment: I would link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa but I think in 2024 the solution actually is to make sure you are using the latest MySQL version with InnoDB which has a higher max key length

Comment: Can you share your users table migration file?

Comment: There error says you have index key length overflow. Check your index and your data, to figure out why it overflow the key length.

Answer (score 0):

In the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` add the following code.

Import Necessary Classes: Ensure that you have imported the necessary classes at the top of the file:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Modify the boot() Method: Add the following line inside the boot() method:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```