# Guidelines for max string length for data entry

Tags: c#, wpf, string, sql-server-ce

So I am building a new WPF application and I started on my first data entry screen. What maxlength do you normally set for your string fields? I got caught out in my last app my making some of the fields too short.

The string fields will be persisted to a sql server compact db via entity framework.

Comment: Depends on what kind of data goes into the field. Free text? Name? Address?

Comment: General strings like Name of something, Description. Is there a guideline?

Comment: I think you should set the maxlenght of a field accordingly to where its data goes. E.g.: If the name-column of your db has a maxlenght of 2000 chars, use 2000 chars as maxlenght.

Comment: Well I am using entity framework code first without a database to start off with, so do you mean just setting the fields to the max length allowed by sqlce?

Comment: My suggestion was for the case, that there is already a database. If not, think of what lenghtes would be appriopriate for your case. I dont think there are guidelines for that, just make sure that there is always enough chars for every possible case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some other posts on StackOverlfow discussing this. You might find this one most helpful: [List of standard lengths for database fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958/list-of-standard-lengths-for-database-fields).

If you know that the field is used for a first name then you know there's no first name that is longer than 200 chars, then don't make it larger than that. As you can see in the post linked above, there's a link to a catalog that suggests first names are in general not longer than 35 chars.

Fields that you don't know what they will contain such as free text (description or such), just make them the maximum size possible. Better safe than sorry!