# SQL varchar column length for business/company names

Tags: mysql, database, varchar

Is there a standard for varchar length relating to storing company/business names?

I have looked everywhere and cannot find an answer.

If not, what would be an ideal length to cover the majority of scenarios?

Comment: Basically it doesn't matter

Comment: As long as you aren't going `text` or blob it is irrelevant. Shoot for 20k :p

Comment: Ok cheers guys! Why the down vote?

Comment: There I added an upvote. Happy coding

Comment: This may be dated http://stackoverflow.com/q/13506832 check out the 5.7 manual too

Comment: If you have an Excel spreadsheet with the names in a column (A in this example), use this in A1 - =MAX(LEN(A2:A65636)) then hit ctrl+shft+enter and A1 will be populated with the current largest string. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here:

## No

There is not in general, though there are some guidelines for some of these *kinds* of fields, for some organisations, in some countries (see answers to [List of standard lengths for database fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20958/781965)).

You'll have to use best judgement. Quick google search the longest I could find was a little over 100 characters - if you're not stuck for space, throw in a few hundred to be safe, otherwise *why* are you strapped for space? Pull it out into a lookup table, then make the column in *that* table wide and move on; angsting over this will not earn you anything.